# Does self-answers count towards the Fiery hat?

Tags: support, self-answer, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

The [description for Fiery](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/fiery) is:

> post five answers that each get a score of at least 3

Does it include self-answers that get a score of at least 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, self-answers count towards the hat.

I received the hat for 4 answers and a self-answer which all received a score of at least 3.

Comment: Here comes the proof :)